# Starcraft 2: How do I enable AI difficulties harder than 'easy'?

Tags: starcraft-2

When I create a game to practice against the AI, it only lets me select 'very easy' and 'easy'. How do I get the other difficulties enabled? Play a certain number of matches? Is it locked until I buy the full game? (Currently playing on the "Starter Edition".)

**Q: How do I enable AI difficulties harder than 'easy'?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your hypothesis is exactly right. Quoting from the [Starter Edition page](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/starcraft-ii-starter-edition-and-guest-pass), emphasis added:

> **What are the Starter Edition restrictions?**
>
> Starter Edition players cannot:
>
> - Use versus and co-op matchmaking
> - Publish custom maps to Battle.net
> - Play offline
> - Chat in public chat channels
> - Join or create clans
>
> For single player and custom games, Starter Edition players can only play as Terran. **Added AI for custom games is limited to Very Easy and Easy difficulty.**